# WPF - Create Context Menu mixing static and dynamic items

Tags: c#, wpf

I try to create Context Menu mixing static and dynamic items.
this is the code:

```
 <CollectionViewSource x:Key="DynamicMenuBridge" Source="{Binding Path=MyMenuCollection}" />
        <ContextMenu x:Key="_Menu"  >
            <ContextMenu.ItemsSource>
                <CompositeCollection>
                    <MenuItem Header="A" Click="..."/>
                    <Separator/>
                    <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource DynamicMenuBridge}}"  >
                    </CollectionContainer>
                    <Separator/>
                    <MenuItem Header="b" Click ="..."/>
                    <MenuItem Header="c" Click="..."/>
                </CompositeCollection>
            </ContextMenu.ItemsSource>
        </ContextMenu>
```

But it does not work, why ?
(in debuging by snoop. it looks like that the CollectionContainer does not exist)

Comment: It looks like invalid markup to me. Where is the `<CollectionContainer>` start tag?

Comment: The problem is not this.
Sorry, the start of the tag was mistakenly dropped when I copied the code to here,  I fixed it

Comment: @efratc did you ever find a solution to this problem? I currently experience the same issues.